# Infragistics Selected Node

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Would like to know if I am the error or I have encountered a bug.

I have a grid with parents and children. I have made buttons to move the nodes from top to bottom and back. This works, but the first selected node remains selected. The node that should be moved can be moved as desired. Why is the first selected node still displayed?

```cs
private void IDC_ARROW_UP_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.UltraTreeNode Node in this.uTreeMenue.SelectedNodes)
    {
        Node.Reposition(Node, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.NodePosition.Previous);
        Node.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Selected node is shown below:

[image]

---EDIT:

```
private void IDC_ARROW_UP_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var NodeSelected = uTreeMenue.SelectedNodes;
    var NodeCount = NodeSelected.Count;
    NodeSelected.SortByPosition();

    if (NodeCount > 0 && NodeSelected[0].PrevVisibleNode is Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.UltraTreeNode Node)
        Node.Reposition(NodeSelected[NodeCount - 1], Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.NodePosition.Next);
}
```

---Same for the Down_Click_Method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below:

```cs
private void IDC_ARROW_UP_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var selected = uTreeMenue.SelectedNodes;
    selected.SortByPosition();
    var cnt = selected.Count;
    if (cnt > 0 && selected[0].PrevVisibleNode is UltraTreeNode node) 
    {                
        node.Reposition(selected[cnt - 1], Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.NodePosition.Next);
    }
}
```

The logic implemented in the code above is very simple. Instead of moving all selected nodes (for example `Canada…France` on the picture below) up the first node located before all the selected items moving after all selected items down:

[image]

Therefore, after moving the node preceding all selected items down (in the test example this is *`Brazil`* item) the `UltraTree` control will be look like below:

[image]

To determine limits of the selected items correctly they are should be sorted by using the `SortByPosition()` method, that sorts the `SelectedNodes` collection such that members appear in the same order they do in the tree.

Comment: Thank you very much, dear stranger.
It worked wonderfully, I don't know why, but it worked.

Comment: @craverealize: You are welcome! I have added more description to my answer to be clear how this works.

Comment: hello @Victor,
thank you very much for the first quick help. at first sight it helped me. unfortunately, i have to admit that i am overqualified in this matter. I would like to move the selected nodes now up and down, but no "groups" should be broken. I hope with the screenshot more understandable what I mean. I click 2 times the button to move down and after clicking up, the "groups" are dissolved. thanks a lot in advance.  https://imgur.com/a/8MeVJtd

Comment: @craverealize: I will be happy to help you, but you should attach full code related to your problem. I think when you describe your problem in detail it will be completely different from the one you described above. What you want to do requires more complex code. Therefore, it would be better if you describe your problem in detail in a new question. It would be better if you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hearing something like this gives me a little hope. thanks a lot man. I edited the main thread because a) I can't write enough characters as comments and b) so the formatting is maintained.

Comment: @Vicor, see above, SO has swallowed your name in the comment